# any other patents involving baseball caps for pigtails?

Tags: ownership, search

Are there any patents out for baseball caps with pigtail/ponytail openings?

Comment: Have you tried searching for them yourself?

Comment: Did you find this abandoned application? https://patents.google.com/patent/US20060010566A1 Specialty hat
Abstract
A specialty hat is constructed with a crown having one or more holes through an upper portion of the crown, where the holes are dimensioned to receive a portion of the hat wearer's hair that is positioned through the hole. Pluralities of decorations are interchangeably and selectively removably attached to the crown adjacent the holes where the decorations appear to be attached to the hair positioned through the holes.

Answer (score 1):

Performing a thorough patent search is a significant effort. Some people make a career of it. I think you should try to do it yourself first and then ask for help if you get stuck. Even though I don't consider myself a professional, here are some tips:

First, it can be useful to do a basic Google search for such products. From this you can see which companies make competitive products. If you see something, you will want to search for that companies patents in particular.

Second, use a patent specific search site. The two free ones I like are [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com) and [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/). I especially like The Lens. Initially just put search terms in and see what pops out. For instance using the terms "baseball cap ponytail" and limiting to US documents yielded 82 hits on The Lens. Be careful not to to be too specific. "Cap" might not find a patent which only uses the term "hat". You can refine the terms, limit the search to US documents, etc.

When you find some relevant patents/applications, look at them for cited patents. This will give you some more prior art. Also, experts use the classification codes to help refine the search. When you find particularly important patents, then it is good to use the [US Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site for research. Here you can review the communications between the examiner and the applicants, see all the prior art the examiner used, determine the legal status of the patent, etc.

With a few hours of work, you should be able to get a pretty good start on identifying relevant patents. Remember, it is the claims that define what the patent is covering. I usually look at the claims and the figures first.

This doesn't eliminate the need for a professional at some point while pursuing your own patent, but doing a search for yourself will greatly speed any subsequent searches (and potentially save you some money).

Comment: I agree on starting with your own search. If you find something dead on you can stop there and save very much time and money. It won't likely save you money on a follow up professional search. A professional searcher would be happy to look at any results you already have but will probably quote you a fixed fee for their search and follow a fairly fixed process as to where and how they search.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I almost always worked with company lawyers and their patent searchers always appreciated getting relevant patents to jump start their searches. However, I did add the word "potentially" to the save some money statement.

Comment: I agree completely that it is helpful and can save time.