# Who specifically has a patent on Fresnel Lenses

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [US8194324](https://www.google.com/patents/US8194324)

I know that the Oculus Rift uses fresnel lenses, but I want to know who specifically holds a patent for fresnel lenses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I contact the owner of a patent?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/how-can-i-contact-the-owner-of-a-patent)

Answer (score 2):

Fresnel lenses date back to the 1700's. I doubt anyone "owns" the basic idea at this point. This is not to say that people don't have patents on novel configurations or methods of constructing fresnel lenses or the use of a fresnel lens in another device. If you are interested in those, you can perform a patent search. Here is a [link](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17010/any-other-patents-involving-baseball-caps-for-pigtails) to an earlier answer where I describe my process of patent searching. A quick search on [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/search?types=Granted%20Patent&l=en&st=true&q=fresnel%20lens&p=0) resulted in 24,157 granted patents 1480 of which have been published in the last 20 years.