# How can I see what exercise/small soft tissue designs are currently patented?

Tags: patent-search, databases

I am a corrective exercise expert, and have some techniques and ideas I would like to see how to protect, and/or what types of things are already protected. Is there a database of specific types of patents I may have access to?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Maybe with an example which is already known by the public?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do a patent search, there are several free sites available. [This answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17010/any-other-patents-involving-baseball-caps-for-pigtails/17011#17011) describes my approach to searching and has links to some sites so you should read that first. Also, you should review this answer which will educate you on the patent system: [Is this patent valid? Granted? Which countries does it cover? Are there family members?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17115/is-this-patent-valid-granted-which-countries-does-it-cover-are-there-family-m/17149#17149).

Once you get a handle on what patents exist and how patents work, then you should be able to ask specific questions related to your own ideas. I suggest however that you shouldn't disclose your ideas publicly before filing for a patent or else you may lose the ability to protect your intellectual property.