# Guides for a newbie patent researcher

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, prior-art-request

I'm a newbie in patent research. I'm presently given a task to find a prior-art on some documents, to be candid, I don't know. Could experts here help suggest A GET STARTED approach? It could be done docs or anything. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for prior art to a patent or patent application?

Comment: My answer to this question might also help. https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17010/17003